# ListView is consuming "SPACE" key on physical keyboard

Tags: android, android-listview

Hi I have a list view which contains custom views which takes input.

I plan to support physical keyboard also.

Everything is working fine, but on "SPACE" key press its behaving in a strange way.

Probably the ListView is taking it as "touch" event, as it's behaving as it is being touched.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
switch (keyCode){

case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SPACE: 
                              handleSpace();
                              break;
```

Above code is in activity which contains the ListView. As the key event is consumed by ListView onKeyDown(..) method is not invoked. Any other key press is passed on to onKeyDown(..). What could be the problem.

Comment: have you set your Activity to Full Screen ?

Comment: Does your activity has `setFocusable(true)` and `setContentView()` ?

Comment: Dear Usama Sarwar, Yes! I have set it to Full Screen.

Comment: Dear Blganesh, It has setContentView(), but no setFocusable(true)